# Node doesn't run the app.js

Tags: node.js

I just started to learn Node.js and was trying to print out Hello World to the terminal but seems like the node doesn't run the file.

my app.js:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

I set my directory to where my app.js file is and when I try `node app.js`, I get nothing. Not even an error or anything.

```
usr-MBP:MEAN ricster$ node app.js
usr-MBP:MEAN ricster$
```

But when I try to run `node` alone then write `console.log('Hello World');` it works.

```
usr-MBP:MEAN ricster$ node
> console.log('Hello World');
Hello World
undefined
>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: that should work - `echo "console.log('hello');" > app.js && node app.js` outputs `hello` to the terminal for me. Have you tried a different terminal? You could also check the exit code (`echo $?`) to see if there were any problems (anything non zero)

Comment: Thank you, trying a different terminal solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying a different terminal solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well, and for me the solution was making sure the file you try to run is saved. When working in graphic text editors, developers may take it for granted that file are constantly autosaved, however otherwise you can just hit Ctr + S and try again. The command in comments is a useful one:

```bash
echo "console.log('hello');" > app.js && node app.js
```

It makes sure the file is indeed saved, for me it started to print ">"s until I forced to break out of it with Ctr + Z. Be extra careful what you try to run.